# Tell VSCode IntelliSense to prefer local header file over one in /usr/local/include?

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

I'm working on a C codebase that I suppose you could call a monorepo. Folder A contains code for various libraries which are used by code in Folder B. When I look at a B file in VSCode and try to jump to the definition of a symbol defined in an A header, VSCode takes me to the A header that's been installed in /usr/local/include by a make rule, instead of the local copy of the header in Folder A.

Is there some way to tell VSCode to prefer the local Folder A version of the header over the /usr/local/include header that it's getting by talking to the compiler about system include paths? I'm not finding anything in the docs for `c_cpp_properties.json` that seems to be able to do this. I'm just a bit concerned that an intern is going to start merrily editing headers in /usr/local/include instead of editing them in Folder A and doing a `make install`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I struggled for a night, and find out two solution finally:

solution 1st: workspace local

- ctrl+shift+p -> Edit Configuration(UI)
- add "-I${workspaceFolder}/" to `Compiler arguments` item
- restart

solution 2nd: global

- open C/C++ setting
- find `Compiler Args`(may has many tabs, like user, remote, workspace, find a proper one for yourself)
- add "-I${workspaceFolder}/"
- restart

this [comment](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/6905#issuecomment-7742459915) inspired me a lot, **it is a feature, not a bug**!

Comment: Wow, it's been long enough that I'm not even working on this C codebase anymore, but this looks like a great solution!